# iOS 7 UIView animateWithDuration:animations:completion: resets its actions at any kind of transformation

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, core-animation, catransition

I recently got a problem with my App.

I usually use

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval) animations:^{...} completion:^(BOOL finished) {...}];
```

to make my animations and it worked perfectly until now. Here's my problem's code

```
UIImageView *someimage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someimage"]];
[someimage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
[self.view addSubView:someimage];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [someimage setFrame:CGRectMake(400, 400, 200, 200)];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"Just finish moving some image lets rotate it!");
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        someimage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"What just happened?");
    }];
}];
```

I got an image and i moved it from one corner to another position using animations. Then, when the animation finishes I rotate it, but when I make that rotation the UIImageView appear at the corner again.

Can someone explain me why this happen and how to handle it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UIView class reference says:

> WARNING   If the transform property is not the identity transform, the
>   value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

Changing a view's (or layer's) frame and its transform at the same time does not work as expected. Instead, change the view's center property.